# CakePHP 2.0: Unexpected Helper Behavior (HtmlHelper::link)

Tags: cakephp, html-helper, cakephp-2.0

I was working on my CakePHP 2.0 and wanted to make a language helper so I don't have to pass a few language based things in my views. For this I created a LanguageHelper.

My first task was to include the language in all links.

```
<?php

    class LanguageHelper extends AppHelper{

        public $helpers = array(
             'Html'
        );

        public function link($title, $url = null, $options = array(), $confirmMessage = false){

            if(!isset($options['lang']) || !$options['lang']){
                  $options['lang'] = Configure::read('Language.default');
            }

            return $this->Html->link($title, $url, $options, $confirmMessage);
        }
    }
?>
```

Now in my view I use the following:

```
<?php echo $this->Language->link('Link', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'home')); ?>
```

Expected result:

```
<a href="/nl-be/admin/pages/home">Link</a>
```

Actual result:

```
<a lang="nl-be" href="/admin/pages/home">Link</a>
```

Even using the following:

```
<?php echo $this->Language->link('Link', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'home', 'lang' => Configure::read('Language.default'))); ?>
```

Gives me a wrong result:

```
<a lang="nl-be" href="/nl-be/admin/pages/home">Link</a>
```

The following is in my routes:

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'app', 'action' => 'defineLanguage'), array('lang' => '[a-zA-Z]{2}[-]{1}[a-zA-Z]{2}'));
Router::connect('/:lang', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'home'), array('lang' => '[a-zA-Z]{2}[-]{1}[a-zA-Z]{2}'));

$prefixes = Configure::read('Routing.prefixes');

foreach($prefixes as $prefix){
    Router::connect('/:lang/' . $prefix, array('prefix' => $prefix, $prefix => true, 'controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'index'), array('lang' => '[a-zA-Z]{2}[-]{1}[a-zA-Z]{2}'));
    Router::connect('/:lang/' . $prefix . '/:controller', array('prefix' => $prefix, $prefix => true), array('lang' => '[a-zA-Z]{2}[-]{1}[a-zA-Z]{2}'));
    Router::connect('/:lang/' . $prefix . '/:controller/:action', array('prefix' => $prefix, $prefix => true), array('lang' => '[a-zA-Z]{2}[-]{1}[a-zA-Z]{2}'));
}
```

Anyone know a way to get the expected result?

EDIT:

I Should also mention that the following does give me the expected result:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link('Link', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'home', 'lang' => Configure::read('Language.default'))); ?>
```

SOLUTION:

```
class LanguageHelper extends AppHelper{

public $helpers = array(
    'Html'
);

public function link($title, $url = null, $options = array(), $confirmMessage = false){

    if(!isset($url['lang']) || !$url['lang']){
    $url['lang'] = Configure::read('Language.default');
    }

    return $this->Html->link($title, $url, $options, $confirmMessage);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still working on 1.3 but I assume that did not changed: you have to put 'lang' parameter into $url array in your helper, not into $options array.

Last line of your helper should be:

```
$this->Html->link($title, array_merge($url, array('lang' => $options['lang']), $options, $confirmMessage);
```

Additionally you should use other variable to avoid unnecessary attribute in your link.

Comment: That did it, I feel really stupid now for mixing those two up. I was doing it right in view when using the Html helper, no idea why I put it in the options afterwards. Thanks a lot!